# Post edit - Media Library - Only get images from current post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, media, attachments, media-library, attachment-fields-to-edit

I've got a few ACF Image fields for `posts` And I want to only query the images in the media library browser already uploaded and used on the current post. In other words, when opening the media library in a image field I only want to see the images of this post.

This is what I came up with. But it doesn't work.

- I can upload a image to one field
- Then in second field I don't see the image from the first field.
- (also after saving the post)
- It now says `no items found`

This is my code:

```
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'show_current_post_attachments', 10, 1);

function show_current_post_attachments($query = array())
{
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'] ;
    $query['post__in'] = [$post_id];

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will lock uploads to “Uploaded to this post” and will not show “All media items” or other options in WordPress media panels.

Add this code to your `function.php` file

```
    add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'firmasite_mediapanel_lock_uploaded' );
    add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'firmasite_mediapanel_lock_uploaded' );
    function firmasite_mediapanel_lock_uploaded() { ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
            // Lock uploads to "Uploaded to this post"
            jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
            jQuery('#media-attachment-filters').remove();
        });
      </script>
    <?php }
```

Comment: It ALMOST works :) You can now see the only images from this post. One problem. I cannot upload a new image and add/select it. The upload works, but after upload I cannot press the `select` button bottom right.

Comment: Also, you can add `jQuery('#media-attachment-filters').remove();` after changing the selected

Comment: Can you please check your console as I did it in mine and there is no issue relate to this I found.

Comment: Ah yes, it throws: `jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') might use property instead of attribute`

Comment: change this jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ) to jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', 'selected' )

Comment: Please upvote and mark as correct answer if this is work for you.

Comment: The console error is gone by changing `.attr()` to `prop()` with `jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').prop('selected', true).parent().trigger('change');`
But upload still fails. 
Hang on I'll disable all my custom code to see if some code of mine interferes

Comment: Still doesn't work on my end. even with default theme and selecting the dropdown manually. In other words, it's not your script but my setup that's not working. Maybe you can still add `jQuery('#media-attachment-filters').remove();` to your solution for other people. It removes the dropdown since it's disabled.